# Is possible to rewrite all values in array without for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, url-rewriting

Let's suppose that we have an array (myArray) with data like this:

```
0: myArray
   content: 'something'
   date: '15.5.2015'
   name: 'Abc'
1: myArray
   content: 'text'
   date: '15.5.2015'
   name: 'Bla'
2: etc ...
```

Now for rewriting all values (into e.g. empty string) of one object properties in this array (for example: 'content') I would use for loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  myArray[i].content = '';
}
```

So result of this would be:

```
0: myArray
   content: ''
   date: '15.5.2015'
   name: 'Abc'
1: myArray
   content: ''
   date: '15.5.2015'
   name: 'Bla'
2: etc ...
```

**My question is:** Is possible to do same result without using loop in javascript? Something like this:

```
myArray[all].content.RewriteInto('');
```

Tnx for ideas.

Comment: you have multiple values. no matter HOW you end up writing this, there's going to be a loop involved somewhere, so just loop over the array and get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you do will end up looping in some fashion. However, *you* don't have to loop...

because we now have functional array methods! You're probably looking for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), perhaps both, since you want to transform (map) each element and/or combine them into one (reduce).

As an example, we can take your data and return a string with all of the `content` fields concatenated using:

```js
var data = [{
  content: 'something',
  date: '15.5.2015',
  name: 'Abc'
}, {
  content: 'text',
  date: '15.5.2015',
  name: 'Bla'
}];

var result = data.map(function(it) {
  return it.content;
}).join(' ');

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

To remove the `content` field from each item, without modifying the input, you can:

```js
var data = [{
  content: 'something',
  date: '15.5.2015',
  name: 'Abc'
}, {
  content: 'text',
  date: '15.5.2015',
  name: 'Bla'
}];

var result = data.map(function(it) {
  return {date: it.date, name: it.name};
});

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
Use it like this :

```
myArray.map(function (data) {
    return data.content = 'value';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the first comment on your question points out you always have to use a loop, but you could monkey patch the Array using prototype like:

```
Array.prototype.rewriteInto = function(key, rewriteVal){
  for(var k in this){
    this[k][key] = rewriteVal;
  }
};

var testData = new Array();
testData.push({
  content: 'something',
  date: '15.5.2015',
  name: 'Abc',
});

testData.push({
  content: 'something',
  date: '15.5.2015',
  name: 'bla',
});

console.log(testData);

testData.rewriteInto('content', '');
console.log(testData);
```

So you don't have to rewrite the loop all the time you want to use this functionality.

See [example](http://jsbin.com/cohivoqaga/1/edit?js,console)